# Store date with char(10), why can compare directly with <,>,= in sybase 15.7

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

The term_date in #report_tmp is char(10), when use <,>, it works as expect,
Is this comparison method reliable in sybase?

```
    declare @last_year_end char(10)

SELECT @last_year_end=convert(varchar,@cyear -1)+'/12'+'/31'


update #report_tmp
set remark = @note1
where term_date != '' and term_date <= @last_year_end
```

Comment: Sybase IQ 15.7? There use no such product. Please provide the results of: select @@version

Comment: @AdamLeszczyński    ，It is Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 26390 SMP SP138 /P/Sun_svr4/OS 5.10/ase157sp138x/4002/64-bit/FBO/Mon Aug 29 09:09:29 2016

Comment: Personally I would always use a datetime or date for any storing of date functions not char() otherwise you can come unstuck with variations in regional settings i.e. UK has dd/mm/yy and US use mm/dd/yyyy and performance issues.

Comment: @RichCampbell ，Actually the table is created by others,and the date in it is 2016/01/31, so the compare works，thx

Comment: Yes but that works for your specific example, however you asked whether a char comparison method is reliable in your question and as a rule it generally isn't.

Comment: @RichCampbell ，Seems need revise the code to fix it ,thx a lot

Comment: If you don't care about the time portion then the normal 'date' datatype is probably your best bet. You can still concatenate the string as you are currently plus checking with greater/less than as your current code does should still work too so not much in the way of code changes.

Comment: @RichCampbell ,noted，Thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

I would rather write this code:

```
declare @cur_year datetime

SELECT @cur_year = convert(datetime, convert(varchar, @cyear) + '/01'+'/01', 111)

update #report_tmp set remark = @note1 
where term_date != '' and term_date < @cur_year
```

Here the you do not rely on the current locale settings when implicitly converting the varchar to date or datetime (would work with both).

Comment: Thx Adam. very helpful